# Register email submitted in website to AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have a website with a email subscription form on it. I was wondering if it was possible to have the subscribe email button register the email that was submitted on my AWS SES account? Is it possible to just use an HTTP post to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "register the email?"

Comment: when someone submits their email address, I want it to add their email to my SES subscription

Comment: What do you mean by add it to SES? What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to create a database of emails?

Comment: In AWS SES console, there is a tab called email address. I would like to add a submitted email to that list

Comment: That tab is for verifying the addresses that you will send from. It isn't for subscriptions or recipient email addresses. If you can try to describe the problem you are trying to solve more broadly it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SES is an SMTP server for sending emails. It is not for the management of subscriptions or contact lists. Email addresses need to be stored and managed somewhere else, such as DynamoDB. If you are looking for an email delivery API that also manages contacts, look at something like SendGrid or Mailchimp.

The "email addresses" tab of SES is for Verified Sender identities, which are addresses that you will be sending email **from**. It is not for storing recipients.

Comment: AWS Pinpoint is an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send an email to multiple subscribers using SES, but in your scenario you should probably be looking at [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) instead. You can use AWS SDK to add subscribers to an SNS topic using the [subscribe function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#subscribe-property), and then simply call [SNS publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property) to publish a message to that topic and it will send an email to all subscribers.

Comment: SES can send to as many people as he wants. SNS would require each user to approve their SNS subscription using a not so friendly AWS generated email.